# ¿Cómo evitar el 'Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 34ms'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

Estoy utilizando `JS` para crear una tabla HTML dado que uso unos datos que primero cargo en matrices, así armó la tabla, lo que sucede es lo siguiente, hay una opción que permite cambiar datos que ya se han ingresado a la tabla, al final del proceso vuelvo a pintar la tabla como cuando se le están insertando nuevos datos, ahí viene el problema, cuando estoy cambiando un dato y no ingresando uno nuevo me aparece la excepción `[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 34ms` y daña el diseño de las tablas, son varias tablas anidadas dentro de una, entonces la crea mal, no las crea de igual tamaño sino que les da un tamaño que va descendiendo según la tabla.

Les mostraré:

Así se deben ver las tablas, así quedan mientras les agregue datos con el formulario de arriba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando uso la opción para modificar uno de los valores que ya se han agregado a la tabla se daña por completo el diseño, cosa que no pasa cuando doy en agregar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven se abren las tablas y no toma los valores que le doy, miro la consola y me aparece ese error.

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 36ms
```

Claro, los tiempos varían, pero n es mucho, a veces es 40, otras 34, otras 36 y así.

Y es raro porque solo tengo un método que dibuja las tablas, ahí las reconstruye y todo funciona como dije, y en si lo hace, solo que no toma los estilos y abre las tablas así.

Quien me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria

Comment: El hecho de que no te muestre la tabla como debiera es un problema completamente aparte de la advertencia que te da Chrome. Es simplemente una advertencia de que un método que manipuló el DOM forzó a recalcularlo (eso es el reflow). Te diría que un alto porcentaje de las operaciones que haces con jQuery fuerzan un reflow, mientras que librerías que usan un shadow-dom como Angular, React o VUE usan un método más eficiente. Preocúpate de que tu tabla se vea como debe y de plano descarta esas advertencias hasta el día en que quieras enfocarte en el performance

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es bastante especifico habría que depurar el código, lo que tocaría hacer es ir comentando porciones de código hasta que no salga el error es un rollo pero es lo que hay.

Seguramente habrás notado que esta pregunta es similar a esta en ingles pero por si acaso te la dejo, puede servirte de referencia.

Aquí se menciona la posibilidad de que sea el navegador que estas usando, checa si te sale el mismo error en otros navegadores, saludos.

[JavaScript task took xx ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms)

Comment: Si tienes razón, algo sucede con la sobre carga de memoria que usa `JavaScript` y hace que pase esto, probé este fin de semana varias veces y cuando me pasaba solo reiniciaba el computador y ya, se resolvía, es como temas de procesamiento del PC que se use, no sé si esto pasará si subo la página a un servidor